# Simple AngularJS Form is undefined in Scope

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm starting to play around with AngularJS forms in jsfiddle and I've come across a problem already where a very simple form example is not working as expected. All I have is a named form and it's not showing up in scope for some reason (I'm expecting a FormController instance).

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/R3B7m/) set up, and below is the basic code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainContainer" ng-app="angularTest" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>The Form</h1>
    <form name="theForm">
        <input name="myName" type="text" ng-model="model.name" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('angularTest', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = { name: 'Model Name' };
    console.log($scope.theForm); //displays 'undefined'
}]);
```

I can't find a lot of straightforward examples of this on jsfiddle, so I wasn't sure if this could be some strange interaction with sites like it (most examples I find aren't using formal controllers). I've tried on Plunker to check as well, but I encounter the same problem.

I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious, but I can't see many other things to change or tweak here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I ran into this problem when my form was nested inside an element with ng-if. Using ng-show instead fixed the problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The form only registers itself with the `$scope` of the controller *after* the controller has initially run. Therefore the `console.log($scope.theForm)` will return undefined even if everything is setup correctly.

In your example to react to the presence of `theForm`, you can setup a watcher on `theForm` to set debug text depending its presence:

```
$scope.$watch('theForm', function(theForm) {
    if(theForm) { 
        $scope.formDebugText = 'Form in Scope';
    }
    else {
        $scope.formDebugText = 'Form is Undefined';
    }        
});
```

which can be seen in action at http://jsfiddle.net/9k2Jk/1/

Comment: Ah, I should have known better. I've already dealt with these types of asynchronous loading behaviors! Thanks! It's all going to sink in eventually ;)

Comment: If you need to check it only once it's worth removing watch after form reports it's presence var formWatchUnbind = $scope.$watch and then if(theForm){formWatchUnbind(); //do w/e you want here}

Comment: this does not work for me. `$scope.theForm` is always undefined

Comment: @michal : Thanks for answer. Any documentation which says 'form' register to scope of controller only when controller had gone through initial run. Would be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 90):

A good way to perform this without using watch (which is a bit overkill) is to define an object in the scope into which you will register the form.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainContainer" ng-app="angularTest" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>The Form</h1>
    <form name="form.theForm">
        <input name="myName" type="text" ng-model="model.name" />
        <input type="button" value="Here the scope" ng-click="display()"/>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('angularTest', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = { name: 'Model Name' };
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.display = function () {
        console.log($scope.form.theForm);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This might not be the best solution to this problem, but it is generally a good way to bring form validation into the controller. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Note trying to bind directly to `form` won't work it must be `form.someNewName`.

Answer (score 32):

What fixed it for me was to use a parent object on the `$scope`.

In the controller:

```
$scope.forms = {};
$scope.registerUser = function registerUser() {
    if ($scope.forms.userForm.$valid) {
        alert('submit');
    }
};
```

In the template:

```
<form name="forms.userForm" ng-submit="registerUser()">
```

The reason:

If you use `<form name="userForm"...` instead of `<form name="forms.userForm"...` it attaches the form to a child scope, but because $scopes use prototypical inheritance, as soon as I declared an empty object literal on the original $scope the form was attached to it instead.

Comment: So I added `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` to the `form` and that seemed to get it to bind directly to that scope. Is there anything wrong about this approach?

Answer (score 23):

This is the recommended way to access form variable:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms - Binding to form and control state

In HTML:

```
<form name="form">  
<input type="button" ng-click="reset(form)" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Youl will pass the name of the form as a variable to the function.

In JS :

```
$scope.reset = function(form) { 
  alert(form); 
};
```

Variable 'form' should NOT be undefined now.

Comment: How would you test this?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I used `ng-include` to generate a sub scope, so within current scope the property is `undefined`, to be safe and prevent sub-scope issue, we should use reversed variable to name the form just like `form.theForm`.

But make sure that **you've declared this form name in your controller in advance**.

```
<form name="form.theForm">
    <input name="myName" type="text" ng-model="model.name" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = { name: 'Model Name' };
    //You have to declare here, else it will trigger undefined error still.
    $scope.form = {
      theForm: {} 
    };

    $scope.reset = function(){
       $scope.form.theForm.$setPristine();
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-initialize the form from your controller before you try to access $scope.form with this line of code. $scope.form will then be available.

```
angular.element(jQuery('.form-control')).triggerHandler('input')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a directive to deal with this issue. Its an attribute that you can put on your form and pass a function to which will execute when the form is ready.

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app').directive('formInit', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      init: '&formInit'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      var name = null;
      if ($element[0] && $element[0].name){
        name = $element[0].name;
      }

      var listener = $scope.$watch('init', function(){
        if ($scope[name] && $scope.init){
          $scope.init();
          listener();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Example HTML**

```
<form name="test" form-init="testing()">
```

Where `testing` is a function on your controllers scope.