# TypeError: Cannot set property '$pristine' of undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, form-control

I am using **AngularJS v1.3.16**. I want to reset the form.

I tried `$pristine`, `$dirty` and `$setPristine()` but I got error messages:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="userForm" class="form-horizontal ut-form form-validation" role="form" name="userForm" novalidate>
.........
</form>
```

**Code:**

```
    $scope.createUser = function () {
        $scope.page.view = 'create';
        $scope.account = "";
        $scope.userForm.$pristine = true;
    }
```

**Error messages:**

1. `$setPristine()` - TypeError: Cannot read property `'$setPristine'` of `undefined`
2. `$pristine` - TypeError: Cannot set property `'$pristine'` of `undefined`

Please can any one suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe it would help to post the **error messages** here as well.

Comment: Where you're calling `reset` method ?

Comment: It may work, please Try ANUSHA --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759221/angularjs-setpristine-to-reset-form

Comment: @Vineet I have already checked this link but no use. I tried according to this example

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436501/simple-angularjs-form-is-undefined-in-scope

Answer (score -1):

you can use the form name for this.

In your case:

```
$scope.userForm.$setPristine()
```

Or directly in the HTML:

```
userForm.$setPristine()
```

Comment: He **is** using form name in his code, and he said he already tried `$setPristine() `

Comment: I have already tried $setPristine() then i got TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined