# $scope.formName.$setPristine() does not work ; How to reset form in angular?

Tags: angularjs

create a form in angular 1.5

`< form name="movieForm" ng-submit="addMovie(movie) ../>`

and when I try to reset the form after form submission using

`$scope.movieForm.$setPristine()`

BUT it gives error in console : ***Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined***

#### form.html

```
<form name="movieForm" novalidate role="form" ng-submit="movieForm.$valid && addMovie(movie)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="movie.name" name="mName" required />
  <input type="text" ng-model="movie.star" name="mStar" />
  <input type="number" ng-model="movie.year" name="mYear" required />  
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  <input type="button" value="Reset" ng-disabled="movieForm.$pristine" ng-click="reset()" />
</form>
```

#### app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('movieController', function($scope) {
      $scope.title = "Home Page";
      $scope.movieData = [{
        name: 'PiKu',
        star: 'Irrfan Khan',
        releaseYear: '2015'
      }];
      $scope.addMovie = function(movie) {
        if(movie && movie.name) {
            $scope.movieData.push({
                name : movie.name,
                star : movie.star,
                releaseYear : movie.year
            });
        }
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.movieForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.movieForm.$setUntouched();
      };

      // **un-commenting below line gives error in console** 

      //$scope.reset();

    });

}());
```

also checked `$scope.movieForm()` in console but its undefined ?

What is the issue?

see the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/seririv/3/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Remove $scope and try

Comment: already tried with less or more examples on SO but no success :(

Comment: I can't see any error in console..

Comment: @Pankaj Please uncomment the `$scope.reset()` method and see

Comment: This Link May Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648427/angular-clear-subform-data-and-reset-validation#answer-18648486

Comment: Please refer to this answer for your issue regarding console logging $scope.movieForm showing as undefined.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436501/simple-angularjs-form-is-undefined-in-scope/22436630#22436630](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436501/simple-angularjs-form-is-undefined-in-scope/22436630#22436630)

Comment: because `form` object haven;t got created when controller got intialized, wrap `reset` function in `$timeout` to make sure it runs one digest cycle later so that form object will also get available `$timeout(function(){         $scope.reset();       })`

Comment: @PankajParkar that does not work either.. why angular has so much frustrating :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `$scope.movieForm` before bindings actually initialized.

---

**Edit**
To be clear: `$setPristine` - not clears form fields. For clearing form fields you can just reset the object that form controls are bound to:

```
$scope.movie = {};
```

[here's](http://jsbin.com/bosojekeco/1/edit?html,js,console,output) working demo

Comment: still same error even on load ,because of timeout :(

Comment: did you injected it? `function($scope, $timeout)`

Comment: it does not reset the form in demo also

Comment: your question was _Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined_. $setPristine is not intended to reset the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115101/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-aleksey-l).

Comment: This does not reset the form after submission, it only works when we click on reset button and also show all hidden error after this  AND I think that can be done using HTML only `<input type="reset">`

Comment: even I was also doing a silly mistake that I havn't add `ng-controller` as this form is in inner page which has different controller than main controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using $setPristine wrong.

"This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form."

So this only clears classes but not the $scope variables. You have to reset $scope.movie variable.

for example I added this default form variable

```
var defaultForm={
  name: "",
  star: "",
  year: ""
}
```

and modified your reset code

```
 $scope.reset = function() {       
        $scope.movie = angular.copy(defaultForm);
        $scope.movieForm.$setPristine();
 };
```

This works fine.

Check out the fiddle.

http://output.jsbin.com/hugiye/2

Comment: still  Error `Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined` :(

Comment: I do not get that which does `$scope.movieForm`  is defined??

Comment: where are you getting error. Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: fiddle is working fine but the same code on my page does not work :(

Comment: cross check the angular version. $setPristine() was introduced in the 1.1.x branch of angularjs.

Comment: I am using angular *1.5.6* , and that JSBin using 1.1.5 :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the angular docs $setPristine():

"This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form."

This only reset classes not the actual scope variable.

If you want to set scope variable to default state then you should reset scope variable too.

`

```
var movie = {
        name: '',
        star: '',
        year: ''
      };
```

and in your reset function you have to add this

```
$scope.movie = angular.copy(movie);
```

`